# Can I select a modified version of a value from a table in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, triggers

I have a strange situation where it would be nice to select a modified value rather than the actual value from a table for a limited time. Ideally, I would like to create a "trigger" that would operate on the selected value, and then when I no longer need the trigger, simply drop it.

Here's an example:

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  FOO_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  SOME_VAL NUMBER
);

INSERT INTO FOO (FOO_ID, SOME_VAL) VALUES (1, 236);

/* Some code that will create the "trigger" which adds 4 to SOME_VAL when selected... */

SELECT * FROM FOO;
```

output:

```
FOO_ID | SOME_VAL
-------+---------
     1 |      240
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: You could create a trigger that fired when the insert executed to change the value.  Or you could rename the table, create a view named `foo`, do the manipulation in the view, and then drop the view and rename the table at some point in the future.

Comment: I can't imagine the use case for this. But, you could update the value (`update foo set some_val = some_val + 4 where foo_id = 1`), _without committing the transaction_, then doing a _rollback_ when you're done.

Comment: I know this is incredibly weird and in no way the "right" way to do things. I would love to just update the value, but I can't. And I have to commit the transaction because this "change" should remain in place potentially for days or weeks. I need to keep the original value intact, though.

Comment: I feel like this is almost a good one for code golf ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't solve this with a trigger. Rather, I would add a CREATED column that defaults to `SYSDATE`. That column is set to the time the row was inserted.

```
CREATE TABLE FOO (
  FOO_ID NUMBER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  SOME_VAL NUMBER,
  CREATED TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT SYSDATE
);
```

The insert statements remain identical. You should not set CREATED explicitly:

```
INSERT INTO FOO (FOO_ID, SOME_VAL) VALUES (1, 236);
```

The select is similar. The difference is that instead of a trigger, we now create a view, from which we select the adapted values.

```
SELECT * FROM FOO_VIEW;
```

The view could be created as follows:

```
CREATE VIEW FOO_VIEW AS
  SELECT FOO_ID,
    CASE
      WHEN SYSDATE < CREATED + 1 THEN SOME_VAL + 4
      ELSE SOME_VAL
    END SOME_VAL
  FROM FOO
```

The special condition is wrapped in a case statement. No need for triggers, only a view was created.

Comment: This is probably the most elegant solution, but it doesn't save me any work in my current setup. I'll go ahead and mark this one accepted, as it provides a great solution considering the given parameters.

Answer (score 1):

I think this can also be done using the virtual column like in the example that you have shared simply `ALTER` the table definition as per your requirement as mentioned value.

```
ALTER TABLE FOO ADD MOD_VAL GENERATED ALWAYS AS (SOME_VAL + 4);
```

Once you have altered the definition insert your record like always (keeping in mind with virtual column you also need to mention the field name while inserting records)

```
INSERT INTO FOO (FOO_ID,SOME_VAL) VALUES (1,236);
```

Now you are good to select your result with the good old SQL `SELECT` statement.

```
SELECT FOO_ID, MOD_VAL FROM FOO;
```

Hope this helps !!!

Comment: A very nice addition! I think this is a pretty good way to keep things simple and (sort of) produce the desired result.

Comment: Thanks Andy. Moreover you have the choice to later drop this field if its not required anymore.